# Using protocol with typealias as a property

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have a protocol with a typealias:

```
protocol Archivable {
    typealias DataType

    func save(data: DataType, withNewName newName: String) throws
    func load(fromFileName fileName: String) throws -> DataType
}
```

and a class that conforms to that protocol:

```
class Archiver: Archivable {
    typealias DataType = Int

    func save(data: DataType, withNewName newName: String) throws {
        //saving
    }

    func load(fromFileName fileName: String) throws -> DataType {
        //loading
    }
}
```

and I would like to use `Archivable` as a property in another class like:

```
class TestClass {

    let arciver: Archivable = Archiver() //error here: Protocol 'Archivable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requiments
}
```

but it fails with

> Protocol 'Archivable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requiments

My goal is that `TestClass` should only see `Archiver` as `Archiveable`, so if I want to change the saving/loading mechanism, I just have to create a new class that conforms to `Archivable` as set it as the property in `TestClass`, but I don't know if this is poosible, and if so, then how.

And I would like to avoid using `AnyObject` instead of DataType.

Comment: read: [the link](http://krakendev.io/blog/generic-protocols-and-their-shortcomings)

Comment: @RMenke thanks for the link, so basically this approach not works :\

Comment: At the moment generics are only partially implemented. One of the goals for Swift 3 is to make it fully generic. Making everything generic is the latest trend, but it just doesn't play nice with how Swift works. Every type has to be known at compile time, and generics in Swift just can't do that yet in every case. I personally try to avoid generics altogether.

Comment: @DánielNagy if you have any free time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285246/heightforrowatindexpath-crashing-intermittently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you are actually trying to do, this can work using type erasure. If you follow the instructions in the link [R Menke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4263818/r-menke) posted in the comments, you can achieve what you are trying to do. Since your property in `TestClass` seems to be a let, I'm going to assume you already know the type of `DataType` at compile time. First you need to setup a type erased `Archivable` class like so:

```
class AnyArchiver<T>: Archivable {
    private let _save: ((T, String) throws -> Void)
    private let _load: (String throws -> T)

    init<U: Archivable where U.DataType == T>(_ archiver: U) {
        _save = archiver.save
        _load = archiver.load
    }

    func save(data: T, withNewName newName: String) throws {
        try _save(data, newName)
    }

    func load(fromFileName fileName: String) throws -> T {
        return try _load(fileName)
    }
}
```

Much like Swift's `AnySequence`, you'll be able to wrap your `Archiver` in this class in your `TestClass` like so:

```
class TestClass {
    let archiver = AnyArchiver(Archiver())
}
```

Through type inference, Swift will type `TestClass`' archiver let constant as an `AnyArchiver<Int>`. Doing it this way will make sure you don't have to create a dozen protocols to define what `DataType` is like `StringArchiver`, `ArrayArchiver`, `IntArchiver`, etc. Instead, you can opt in to defining your variables with generics like this:

```
let intArchiver: AnyArchiver<Int>
let stringArchiver: AnyArchiver<String>
let modelArchiver: AnyArchiver<Model>
```

rather than duplicating code like this:

```
protocol IntArchivable: Archivable {
    func save(data: Int, withNewName newName: String) throws
    func load(fromFileName fileName: String) throws -> Int
}
protocol StringArchivable: Archivable {
    func save(data: String, withNewName newName: String) throws
    func load(fromFileName fileName: String) throws -> String
}
protocol ModelArchivable: Archivable {
    func save(data: Model, withNewName newName: String) throws
    func load(fromFileName fileName: String) throws -> Model
}

let intArchiver: IntArchivable
let stringArchiver: StringArchivable
let modelArchiver: ModelArchivable
```

I wrote a post on this that [goes into even more detail](http://krakendev.io/blog/generic-protocols-and-their-shortcomings) in case you run into any problems with this approach. I hope this helps!

Comment: I read you post about generic protocols and I liked it. You are good in explaining things. But one thing confuses me - absence of "generic protocol" words in "The Swift Programming Language" book because there are no generic protocols in Swift :)

Comment: Look up associated types. I call them generic protocols because they closely resemble generic classes and are less concrete by nature.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to declare and assign `archiver`:

```
let archiver: Archivable = Archiver()
```

it must have concrete type. 
`Archivable` is not concrete type because it's protocol with associated type.

From "The Swift  Programming Language (Swift 2)" book:

> An associated type gives a placeholder name (or alias) to a type that
>   is used as part of the protocol. The actual type to use for that
>   associated type is not specified until the protocol is adopted.

So you need to declare protocol that inherits from `Archivable` and specifies associated type:

```
protocol IntArchivable: Archivable {
    func save(data: Int, withNewName newName: String) throws

    func load(fromFileName fileName: String) throws -> Int
}
```

And then you can adopt this protocol:

```
class Archiver: IntArchivable {
    func save(data: Int, withNewName newName: String) throws {
        //saving
    }

    func load(fromFileName fileName: String) throws -> Int {
        //loading
    }
}
```

There are no truly generic protocols in Swift now so you can not declare `archiver` like this:

```
let archiver: Archivable<Int> = Archiver()
```

But the thing is that you do not need to do so and I explain why.

From "The Swift  Programming Language (Swift 2)" book:

> A *protocol* defines a blueprint of methods, properties, and other requirements that suit a particular task or piece of functionality.

So basically when you want to declare `archiver` as `Archivable<Int>` you mean that you don't want some piece of code using `archiver` to know about its concrete class and to have access to its other methods, properties, etc.
It's obvious that this piece of code should be wrapped in separate class, method or function and `archiver` should be passed there as parameter and this class, method or function will be generic.

In your case `TestClass` can be generic if you pass `archivable` via initializer parameter:

```
class TestClass<T, A: Archivable where A.DataType == T> {
    private let archivable: A

    init(archivable: A) {
        self.archivable = archivable
    }

    func test(data: T) {
        try? archivable.save(data, withNewName: "Hello")
    }
}
```

or it can have generic method that accepts `archivable` as parameter:

```
class TestClass {        
    func test<T, A: Archivable where A.DataType == T>(data: T, archivable: A) {
        try? archivable.save(data, withNewName: "Hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: "When you try to declare and assign archiver:

`let archiver: Archivable = Archiver()`

it must have concrete type."
That's not actually correct.  That particular line of code is perfectly legal.  The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan That line of code is not legal and gives compiler error `Protocol 'Archivable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`. The question is all about this error.

Comment: The compilation error is not because that line is illegal but because of the way the class and/or protocol were defined.  See my answer below.  That line compiles just fine.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan The compilation error is because that line is illegal in context of other code that OP posted in his question and I'm answering it.

Answer (score -1):

Hector gives a more complex though ultimately better solution above but I thought I'd post an alternative take on the answer anyway.  It is simpler but probably less flexible in the long term.

```
typealias DataType = Int

protocol Archivable {
    var data: DataType { get set }

    func save(data: DataType, withNewName newName: String) throws
    func load(fromFileName fileName: String) throws -> DataType
}

class Archiver: Archivable {
    var data:DataType = 0

    func save(data: DataType, withNewName newName: String) throws {
        //saving
    }

    func load(fromFileName fileName: String) throws -> DataType {
        return data
    }
}

class TestClass {
    let arciver: Archivable = Archiver()
}
```

Comment: did you just place the `typealias` in the global scope? That makes it non-generic

Comment: Yes I did.  Yes it does.  The unaltered line you said was illegal is now legal.

Comment: Let's solve all problems like that.... It compiles fine, but it doesn't do what we need it to do.